# NullReferenceException юнити система инвентаря

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу систему инвентаря, есть класс предмета:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Sprite Img;

    public Item(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Img = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/items/" + name + ".png");
    }
}
```

Класс слота:

```cs
public class Slot
{
    public enum Type
    {
        STORAGE,
        HEAD,
        BODY,
        LEGS,
        BELT
    }

    public int Id;
    public bool Empty;
    public Item ItemInSlot;
    public Type SlotType;

    public Slot(int id, Type type)
    {
        Id = id;
        Empty = true;
        ItemInSlot = null;
        SlotType = type;
    }
}
```

И класс DataBase со всеми предметами:

```cs
public class DataBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> Items;

    private void Start()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item(0, "test-item-1"),
            new Item(1, "test-item-2"),
            new Item(2, "test-item-3")
        };
    }
}
```

В скрипте, который висит на панели инвентаря есть функция AddItem():

```cs
    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inventory.Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory.Slots[i].Empty)
            {
                inventory.Slots[i].Empty = false;
                inventory.Slots[i].ItemInSlot = item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Эту функцию я вызываю на старте и при запуске ошибка NullReferenceException.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryStorage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DataBase Data;

    public int InventorySize;
    public GameObject SlotPrefab;

    private Inventory inventory;

    private void Start()
    {
        inventory = new Inventory(InventorySize);
        DrawSlots();

        AddItem(Data.Items[0]);
    }
```

Ошибка на 20 строке AddItem(...);
В инспекторе все поля скрипта заполнены. В чём может быть проблема?
Я знаю что это за ошибка, но не могу найти где в коде используется null.
Полный текст ошибки:

> ***NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> InventoryStorage.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/InventoryStorage.cs:20)***

Comment: Проблема однозначно в том, что у вас поле NULL. Приложите текст ошибки, на какой строке возникает.

Comment: А где вы инициализируете `Data`? Там явно `null`, вы ему ничего не присвоили после объявления `public DataBase Data;`

Comment: @CrazyElf это публичное поле, я его инициализирую в инспекторе

Comment: @aqkrie Ну, это как-то как-то. Чем вы его инициализируете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public DataBase Data; // null
```

После такого объявления в `Data` находится `null` - значение по умолчанию для объектов `reference type`, в частности для классов.

```
AddItem(Data.Items[0]);
```

Вы тут берёте `.Items` от `null`, вот и выходит ошибка. Вам надо как-то проинициализировать поле `Data` - присвоить туда новый объект типа `DataBase`, например, но и после этого будет та же ошибка, поскольку в `Data.Items` будет снова `null`, надо заполнить ещё и это поле.

```
public List<Item> Items; // null
```

Comment: В поле Data я кидаю камеру, на которой висит скрипт DataBase, по идее это должно оработать, т.к. работало с другими скриптами. Если проблема действительно в этом, то как тогда инициализировать, если DataBase это MonoBehaviour класс?

Comment: Если инициализировать поле Data, почему Data.Items = null?

Comment: "По идее это должно работать": ну вот не работает же. Если работало в других скриптах - смотрите в чём разница.

Comment: @aqkrie Потому что опять же они ничем не инициализированы `public List<Item> Items;` в них что-то будет только после вызова метода `Start` там